# How to pass an ellipsis argument to a function mocked with testify?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testify

I'm using [testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) for my unit tests and I have a mock structure created by [mockery](https://github.com/vektra/mockery).

My interface looks like this:

```golang
type Foo interface {
  Bar(...interface{})
}
```

Mockery creates the following struct using testify:

```golang
type Foo struct {
    mock.Mock
}

// Error provides a mock function with given fields: v
func (_m *Foo) Bar(v ...interface{}) {
    var _ca []interface{}
    _ca = append(_ca, v...)
    _m.Called(_ca...)
}
```

How can I use this mock struct passing an ellipsis argument to its functions?

Currently I am doing this:

```golang
mockFoo := &mocks.Foo{}
mockFoo.On("Bar", mock.Anything).Return()
```

But when I run my unit tests I get an error:

```
Error(string,*errors.errorString)
                0: "Error sending message"
                1: &errors.errorString{s:"error"}

The closest call I have is:

Error(string)
                0: "mock.Anything"

Provided 1 arguments, mocked for 2 arguments
Diff: 0: PASS:  (string=Error sending message) == (string=mock.Anything)
        1: FAIL:  (*errors.errorString=error) != (Missing)
```

How can I avoid this and call the On method using one or more arguments?